# How to configure Eclipse to write C++ better?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, header

I used to use [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) to do C++ development on Linux. It is awesome to develop a C/C++ project in, but recently I have to switch to [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29). How do I use Eclipse to write C++ code more effectively?

1. Auto-complete. Is there any good plugin for Eclipse? In Eclipse, this have to do with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, and sometimes I thought a quick drop list after I typed a few character is more cool.
2. C++ header list. When I want to include other libraries' header, for example the [ACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Communication_Environment) header, I have to type the whole header name. Is there any way to configure Eclipse, like Qt Creator, when I type the `#include "../ "` the parent header file will be shown in a drop list?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Auto-complete [...] I thought a quick drop list after I typed a few character is more cool.

If you're in the middle of typing a name, the auto-complete drop-down will appear if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Also, the drop-down is configured to appear automatically soon after typing `.`, `->`, or `::`. If that doesn't work for you, check your preferences under "C/C++ → Editor → Content Assist". There is a section called "Auto-Activation". Make sure those boxes are checked.

> 2) C++ header list [...]

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> at some point after typing `#include<` or `#include "` to get the drop-down. It will give you the list of files and folders that it finds.

I'm assuming you're using Eclipse CDT (that is, the standard Eclipse IDE for C++ development).

Comment: well ,what you said about header autocomplete in droplist format is right, but the autocomplete about usual compltete when in the middle of type, it is not so good as QtCreator. I hope i can find other plugin to do this well

Comment: @cui Good luck. Consider posting whatever you find back here so that others can learn about it.